# In Haskell, is there an abstraction for the <?>-operator?

Tags: haskell, option-type, alternative-functor

I just found myself writing this code:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

x = mA <|> mB <?> c

(<?>) :: Maybe a -> a -> a
Just x  <?> _ = x
Nothing <?> y = y
```

Where `mA :: Maybe a`, `mB :: Maybe a`, `c :: a`, and `x :: a`. Basically, the code says: pick the first alternative that is not `empty` and default to `c`. You can call it "reverse Maybe monad" where the analogy to `<?>` would be `pure`.

Equivalently, I could have written

```
Just x = mA <|> mB <|> pure c,
```

but I feel uncomfortable with the irrefutable pattern. Or, of course,

```
x = fromMaybe c (mA <|> mB)
```

because `fromMaybe === flip <?>`.

The `<?>` operator is inspired from parsec. I always get suspicious when I find myself defining utility functions like that, but I couldn't find this defaulting behavior anywhere.

Apparently `Alternative` and `Applicative` are not powerful enough.

Did I miss a type-class?

Comment: FWIW: `<?>` in `parsec` gives a parser human readable name. It doesn't affect actual parsing in anyway.

Comment: So really `(<?>) = flip fromMaybe`? Seems like the standard library provides what you want, just not quite in the form you'd like it to be. Also of course this isn't part of `Applicative` or `Alternative`, because how would that work for other instances, like lists?

Comment: @phadej You're right. In parsec `<?>` does not imply defaulting. So my analogy is weak.

Comment: `(?:) = flip fromMaybe` now found its way in my code everywhere. Clean and simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to leave things at `(<?>) = flip fromMaybe`.

If you'd like to generalize though, `Foldable` seems to be the simplest class with a notion of emptiness:

```
(<?>) :: Foldable t => t a -> a -> a
ta <?> a = foldr const a ta
```

This returns `a` if `ta` is empty or else the first element of `ta`. Examples:

```
Just 0 <?> 10 == 0
Nothing <?> 0 == 0
[] <?> 10 == 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I don't like `<?>` operator name for what you are looking for.
If you search for `Maybe a -> a -> a` type on [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) you can find `?:` operator from `errors` package.

And this operator is so called *elvis*-operator. It is used in Groovy in that form. And [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) also had it. This operator helps to deal with nulls in imperative language. But if you imagine that `Maybe a` is some kind of nullable type then `?:` operator makes sense for you as well. You can observe fact that there is some history behind `?:` operator.

Also, `<?>` is already used in some packages like [megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec), [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec), [optparse-generic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-generic) and others. And your project may use one of those with high probability. So you may experience some conflicts using your version of *elvis*-operator.

Comment: Oh sure, `?:` would be a more sensible choice.

Answer (score 3):

The only two abstraction of "emptyness" I can think on top of my head are:

First, `MonadError`: `Maybe` could have `instance MonadError () Maybe`. See however https://github.com/ekmett/mtl/issues/27

Second, `lens` [`_Empty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Empty.html#v:_Empty),
which is by default comparison (`Eq`) with `mempty` (of `Monoid`). However `Monoid` and `Alternative` disagree for `Maybe`.

Yet I don't recall any operator directly working on either one above.